# Running WSReset.exe with CreateProcess or system

Tags: windows, winapi, createprocess

I'm trying to run WSReset.exe on Windows 10 but keep getting a file not found error. The WSReset.exe is definitely in "C:\Windows\System32\WSReset.exe" but a CMD/Powershell window started from my program cannot seem to find it. But a CMD/Powershell window started outside my program does execute the file.

```
STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo;
ZeroMemory(&processInfo, sizeof(processInfo));
int t = (CreateProcess(L"C:/Windows/System32/wsreset.exe", L"", NULL, NULL, TRUE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo));
    WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);
```

or

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO ShExecInfo = { 0 };
ShExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
ShExecInfo.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
ShExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpVerb = NULL;
ShExecInfo.lpFile = L"C:/Windows/System32/wsreset.exe";
ShExecInfo.lpParameters = L"";
ShExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
ShExecInfo.nShow = SW_SHOW;
ShExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&ShExecInfo);
```

Produces the "Windows cannot find..." error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is 32 bits. Oddly System32 = 64 bit, SysWOW64 = 32 bit. So when I call "C:/Windows/System32/wsreset.exe" windows will turn it into "C:/Windows/SysWOW64/wsreset.exe" and there is no wsreset.exe at that location.

The solution is to disable redirection before calling CreateProcess/ShellExecuteEx/System.

```
//Disable redirection
PVOID OldValue = NULL;
Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection(&OldValue);

STARTUPINFO info = { sizeof(info) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION processInfo = { 0 };
CreateProcess(L"C:/Windows/System32/WSReset.exe", L"", NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL, NULL, &info, &processInfo);
WaitForSingleObject(processInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
CloseHandle(processInfo.hProcess);
CloseHandle(processInfo.hThread);

//Enable redirection (important, otherwise program can crash)
Wow64RevertWow64FsRedirection(OldValue);
```